# After searching in Explorer, how to get a full path in the address bar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, search

When I `ctrl+f` search in File Explorer and click a resulting folder, Instead of the address bar providing a useful path while I'm inside the folder, it instead does the following:

```
    What Windows does (boo):
Where I searched from: D:\Dev (looking for "Library")
Where I am now:        D:\Dev\Library 
Address Bar display:   [] > Search Results in Dev > Library
Address Bar editing:   search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Dev&crumb=location:D%3A%5CDev\Library
Hitting ../ up arrow:  limbo / purgatory???

    What I would be very happy with it doing instead:
Where I searched from: D:\Dev (looking for "Library")
Where I am now:        D:\Dev\Library 
Address Bar display:   D:\Dev\Library
Address Bar editing:   D:\Dev\Library
Hitting ../ up arrow:  D:\Dev
```

If I navigate into a deeper directory, the address bar will display the same breadcrumbs but at least give me a useful path upon clicking on it.

```
Where I searched from: D:\Dev (looking for "Library" -> navigated into "glm")
Where I am now:        D:\Dev\Library\glm 
Address Bar display:   [] > Search Results in Dev > Library > glm
Address Bar editing:   D:\Dev\Library\glm 
Hitting ../ up arrow:  D:\Dev\Library (once more sends me to before time existed)
```

Is there anything I can do to remedy this?  I want the absolute path in the address bar, as Windows would expect me to type it.  I couldn't find any settings in the registry that felt related enough to mangle.

Comment: The windows search inside the Explorer is an integral part of Windows. As far as I know it can't be changed, configured or replaced. The only way I know is to ignore it and use alternative programs (Agent Ransack, Search Everything, ...)

Comment: If I am reading this correctly.. look at the file or folder that you want the path to, hold down [SHIFT] and right click it.  Choose "copy as path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Search Results` window:

1. Select the folder
2. Right-click to display the context menu
3. Select `Open folder location`

[image]

[image]

[image]